# Changing UIButton of a ViewController from another ViewController in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have two ViewController say A, B and C A contains arrays of UIBUtton and a function. The function uses a tag to identify the button pressed, There is a button (the red x button) that displays B ontop of A with a menu, when the menu (i.e B) is clicked it removes controller B before navigating / push to view controller C. This works well.

The red button in controller A rotates from "x" to "+" when clicked. If its "+" the controller B is displayed if "x" its removed. The problem is when am on C and I go back the button still remains as "+" instead of "x" the default state.. I have tried a lot solution from SO using delegate but none tend to solve my problem. Below are the screenshot and code have worked on so far

[image: Screenshot of ViewController B ontop of A]

View Controller A

```
@IBAction func didPressTab(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (sender.tag != 2) {
            let previousIndex = selectedIndex
            selectedIndex = sender.tag

            buttons[previousIndex].isSelected = false
            let previousVC = contentViewControlers[previousIndex]

            previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
            previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

            sender.isSelected = true

            let vc = contentViewControlers[selectedIndex]
            addChildViewController(vc)

            vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
            contentView.addSubview(vc.view)

            vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

            buttons[2].setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel"), for: .normal)
            toogle = false
        } else {
            selectedIndex = sender.tag
            //buttons[selectedIndex].isSelected = false
            if (!toogle) {
                buttons[selectedIndex].setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "add"), for: .normal)
                buttons[selectedIndex].isSelected = true
                let vc = contentViewControlers[selectedIndex]
                addChildViewController(vc)

                vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
                contentView.addSubview(vc.view)

                vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
                toogle = true
            } else {
                buttons[selectedIndex].setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel"), for: .normal)
                let previousVC = contentViewControlers[selectedIndex]

                previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
                previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
                previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()
                toogle = false
            }
        }


     }
func normalizeView() {

        buttons[2].setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cancel"), for: .normal)

        toogle = false
    }
```

ViewController B (When the menu is clicked)

```
@IBAction func menuClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if (sender.tag == 0) {
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let CViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass_code") as! CViewController

            present(CViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else if (sender.tag == 1) {
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let profileViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profile") as! ProfileViewController

            present(profileViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let AViewControler = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboard") as! AViewController

        //This is the code that tries to change the button from "+" back to default "x" but trows an error that an optional value is nil
        AViewControler.normalizeView()

       //This removes A from the view
        willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParentViewController()

    }
```

Comment: Please try by changing let AViewControler to let aViewControler. And check the value for aViewControler is nil or not.

Comment: @Vini App the naming convention used in this question is not the exact naming convention I used in the code, it's just for easy understanding on SO. The issue is that whenever I call the button in aViewController in B it throws an error that an optional value is nil

Comment: Can you check iff AViewControler is nil or not, when you are calling storyBoard.instantiateViewController ?

Comment: @Vini App nope it's not